# How to convert xml to shape file?

Tags: c#, xml

I create a input xml using latitude and longitude point related to street map.
when i optimize this input xml file with fleet engine server then fleet engine create a ouput xml file.
Now i want this input and output xml file using convert shape file.
how to convert xml file into shape file?

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on XML file, I am not sure about the Fleet Engine server, but if the XML file contains Geometry in WKT (Well Know Text) then you can import the XML file in PostGIS or Spatialite. Form there you can export the file as shapefiles using the tools provided. If the geometry is not in WKT then you can still import the xml in PostGIS and then you can manipulate the data and create geometry field. After that you can use the command line tool to export spatial table to shapefile.